# do classic ASP application launch Firefox as default?

Tags: firefox, asp-classic

I am currently working with a classic ASP web application. What I'm wondering about is how it knows which browser to launch, I've looked over everything and am unable to find anywhere that it says to Launch Firefox in order to open the application. If i have firefox uninstalled, then it launches Chrome, however, when I hvae both Chrome and Firefox, then Firefox launched even if I have Chrome set as my default browser. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default browser is a different setting than the "open this file type with this program" setting. If double-clicking an `.asp` file opens in Firefox, then that's the latter type of setting.

To change it, right-click an `.asp` file, choose the "Open with >" option, then "Choose default program...".

That all said, 99.999% of users will never have occasion to double-click an `.asp` file, because most of us don't use web servers as our normal everyday computers.

Answer (score 3):

your asp code has no connection whatsoever with what browser is used, it's browser independent. in order for you web app to run, you must open a browser FIRST, then go to the url of your web app, which will then fire off the asp code. It would be a huge security issue if i went to a web site, and it decided to open a different browser on my computer!

if you want to set Chrome as your default browser, follow these instructions:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

for firefox - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-change-your-default-browser-windows-10

for IE - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17435/windows-internet-explorer-make-default-browser

Comment: The thing is even if i set chrome as default it still opens Firefox. I believe it must be hardcoded somewhere. Thank you though

Comment: are you trying to open an ASP file directly? I guess I'm confused on the steps you're taking on getting FF to open...